# Killing my excel object

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am killing a excel sheet generated by my code (VB.Net).
Code : 
Dim processId As IntPtr 
Process.GetProcessById(processId.ToInt32())

It works on my local machine,but as i debugg on server side it will return processId as 0.

Comment: You havent given ANY answer to your 8 other questions a rating that it indeed answered your question. Can you start closing some of your previous questions where a sufficient answer was provided? Thank you.

Comment: How are your creating the process? For example if I create a process by doing something like Process.Start("MyExcelFile.xlsx") this will return the process that is opened to run the Excel file. This could be Excel itself.

If I then run Process.Start("MySecondExcelFile.xlsx") since I never closed the first instance of Excel this file will be opened in the first one.  The second process will not have the process id of the first process.

Comment: Creating excel using microsoft interop service.now want to get the process id of the generated excel sheet and need to kill it.it works on local machine but not on server(VB NET)